# WPF Drag events Is Handled By Parent also

Tags: wpf, events, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am trying to implement form designer. In which I have a **panel** that contain  another element and so on.Each dragable/dropable element will be an **UserControl**. I have created a common behavior for **FrameworkElements** and is applied for each dragable/dropable element. The problem is,  when I drag over an element inside another element say a textBox Inside a panel, the dragover/dragenter events (drag events) are fired on both the parent and child. How to avoid firing events on the parent/container.

Comment: Is there a property called `Handled` in received event args? Try setting it to `true` in a method where you handle the event and it should stop propagation to the rest of the visual tree (other components).

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have already tried that.Here the problem is not the continues propagation of events the event handling is moving from child to parent then parent to child and continues . so each event is a fresh event.